# Under what conditions is testing $H_0: \theta\leq \theta_0$ v.s. $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$ equivalent to testing simple hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I read somewhere that it is possible to convert a test $H_0: \theta\leq \theta_0$ v.s. $H_1: \theta > \theta_0$ equivalent to simple (point) hypothesis. I am wondering if there is a theorem encapsulating this? I would like to convert the composite hypothesis above into a simple one so that I can use the Neyman-Pearson Lemma. Does anyone have any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Thanks for fixing that.  It makes your question much clearer.

Comment: I think you are looking at this in reverse.  The Neyman-Pearson Lemma came first.  Later it was used to construct uniformly most powerful tests UMP (when they exist) by showing that the likelihood ratio is monotonic. Thus extending the optimality of the likelihood ratio test to composite hypotheses.

Comment: Taking your question literally there are no conditions that makes the proposed composite hypothesis equivalent to testing a simple hypothesis.